# Referencing another section/heading in the same document

Tags: style, quotes, reference, typography

[This German *taz* article](http://www.taz.de/!132260/) includes a same-document reference to another section:

> #### Die Technik
>
> […] Das liegt an dem aus zwei Schichten bestehenden Display *(siehe Öko-Faktor)*.
>
> #### Das Betriebssystem
>
> […]
>
> #### Der Öko-Faktor
>
> […]

The »(siehe Öko-Faktor)« is italicized, and it’s a reference to the section titled »Der Öko-Faktor«.

(While they could/should have used a hyperlink here, let’s assume that this is not a hypertext document, so this question should apply to any kind of document.)

- Are there any rules in German that handle such cases?
- Do you have to use quotes (or as an alternative, italics) for such references?
- But would not only the actual heading part have to be quoted/italicized? I.e., »Öko-Faktor« but not the parentheses and the »siehe«.
- Should the heading be referenced in full? I.e., including the »Der«.

Comment: The *taz* often uses a not very formalized language, so your example may be misleading. There are often house-rules - quotes *can* be used - also the word "siehe" is in the meta level - to include "Der" reads bad.

Comment: This is rather a typesetting question, than a question on German. Maybe you should ask on tex.sx.

Answer (score 8):

DIN 1422-1 §5.1.3 sets the applicable norm. It only says to use parentheses. Section numbers and pages are not applicable here, so the section should be used. There are no stylistic norms set. The linked article adheres to this norm.

DIN 2340 §2.2.1.1 c) allows a shortening of `Der Öko-Faktor` to `Öko-Faktor` and defines such a shortening as „einteiliges Abbrechakronym“. The only further norm set in this DIN is, that a document should stick to one kind of shortening.

[Liste der DIN-Normen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_DIN-Normen)

Comment: Ja ;) - dass es dazu ne DIN gibt hätt ich jetzt nicht gedacht. +1